# Can Html Helpers be used outside of a Razor page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, actionlink

I have a class 'IncomeStatement' that is used as a ViewModel. This class has a property that generates some fairly complicated html like this:

```
public MvcHtmlString HtmlPeriods { get; set; }
.... 
StringBuilder htmlPeriods = new StringBuilder(100);
htmlPeriods.AppendFormat(
"<td><a href='/Forecast/IndexPeriod?Period={1}'>{0}</a></td>",
    inc.NetSales, per.Period.PeriodID);
....
HtmlPeriods = MvcHtmlString.Create(htmlPeriods.ToString())
```

Then in the Razor file I use the HtmlPeriods property, which works fine:

```
<th></th>@Model.HtmlPeriods<td></td>
```

But what if I want to use the Html.ActionLink(...) in my class to create 
nice Razorlike links, 
something like this:

```
string forecastLink = 
Html.ActionLink("Edit Forecast", "/Forecast/IndexEdit?PeriodID=2005Q1");
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [HtmlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx) class to do this. I think you will want the [GenerateLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505148.aspx) method.

Example:

```
string link = HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext, System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes, "My link", "Default", "Index", "Home", null, null);
```

Comment: May need to wrap this inside `MvcHtmlString.Create()` so it won't escape the html created.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation it would be more correct to define HTML helpers instead of using properties and methods on your models. For example:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString HtmlPeriods(this HtmlHelper<SomeViewModel> html)
    {
        // here you can use html.ActionLink in order
        // to generate the desired markup

        // you also have access to the view model here:
        SomeViewModel model = html.ViewData.Model;

        ... 
    }
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@Html.HtmlPeriods()
```

Comment: Darin - I agree that a helper would be better in most cases. However in this case I need to process sequential year records of a database table (vertical ordering) and present them in a horizontal fashion. My first approach was to have a 'foreach year' loop in a helper for each field in the table - not very eficient.

Comment: Now I do more html work in the ViewModel (agains the rules - I now) looping through the year records once, adding to StringBuilders to be used as html rows in the razor page. So one foreach instead of about 30.

Comment: @Dick de Reus, I am not sure I understand what you are taking about without showing some code. Every code could be refactored and optimized in HTML helpers. What you describe is better suited to a helper IMHO.